# How to set password protection for pdf generated using ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to set password protection for PDF reports using ssrs 2008. But PDF is generated promting password but without any content. Is it possible to generate pdf with password protection in SSRS 2008? If not what is alternate ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution as well for a similar task and I've found this

To programmatically generate password protected PDF documents, I would suggest you using the following steps:

1. Use the file shared delivery to generate the PDF documents on a shared folder.
2. Use the web service API supported by Adobe to encrypt the PDF documents with a password value.
3. Program a Windows service to attach the PDF documents to a E-mail, and send the mail on timer.

For more information, please see:
File Share Delivery in Reporting Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159264(SQL.90).aspx
Quick Start: Encrypting a PDF document using the web service API: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000818.html

I will also update you shortly with some other solutions.